# with pd.Series method how to set column datatype as mutable datatype, such as list with str element

Tags: python, pandas, types, series, dtype

I want to create a empty pandas dataframe,

```py
dictdata = {"intfield": pd.Series(dtype='int16'),
            "floatfield": pd.Series(dtype='float32'),
            "strfield": pd.Series(dtype='str'),
            "listfield": pd.Series(dtype='array(str)'), ---- how to write here?
           }
pddata = pd.DataFrame(dictdata)
```

pddata = pd.DataFrame(dictdata) create a empty dataframe data successfully with listfield(list of str element)

Answer (score 0):

```
"listfield": pd.Series(dtype=object)
```

`dtype=object` can hold any type of Python object, so you can store `lists` of strings in the listfield column.